# How to configure AirPort Extreme as the DHCP/DNS/NAT server where DSL modem/router does them?

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp, nat

I have an AirPort Extreme BS and a modem/router (ISP's NetMaster). I want to host my own websites from my Mac Mini with OS X Server. At the moment, ISP's router is the DHCP/DNS/NAT server, and AirPort Extreme is in bridge mode. I want to change it to make it easier to control all the network issues from one place and easily and probably with higher performance.

I have tried using AirPort Extreme in DHCP and NAT mode, but it was not working. I was not able to publish my websites. Then turned the DHCP mode off from the router's web GUI. But did not work. there was a double NAT error and it was clear, there were two routers in the network and they were doing NAT at same time. So I turned off the router's router mode and changed it to bridge mode. what could go wrong then? I lost internet connection. and it took my three hours to refine the router's web GUI since it did not load 192.168.0.1 again. and had to rechange it to router mode and turned DHCP Server mode on again, and turned AirPort Extreme's DHCP and NAT mode to Bridge Mode. Now it works and I am at where I started.

Does it deserve this? I mean using AirPort as the router has more pros than cons?
And anyone who can help me out there?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue. I'm having the same problem